# SQL Transpose Pivot ? UnPivot?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table name table1

```
Partnumber | Model    
12345      | A1    
12345      | B2    
12345      | C3
```

I would like my output to be:

```
Partnumber | Model1 | Model2 | Model3    
12345      | A1     | B2     | C3
```

With the model columns N being dynamic.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hundreds of examples of this on SO.....

Answer (score 1):

You can use dynamic conditional aggregation:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql = 
'SELECT
    PartNumber' + CHAR(10) +
    STUFF((
        SELECT DISTINCT
            '   ,MAX(CASE WHEN Model = ''' + Model + ''' THEN Model END) AS ' + QUOTENAME(Model) + CHAR(10)
        FROM Tbl
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 0, '') +
'FROM Tbl
GROUP BY PartNumber;';

PRINT @sql;
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```